# How to push object inside the array using setState reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

### My State in Class Component

The below given state is in my class component.

I Need to add following example dynamic objects inside the starttime Array.

```
this.state = {
   frequency: {
       starttime: [],
   },
};
```

example objects which are given below.

```
{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"},
{time:"01:30",timezone:"UST"}
```

The above objects were comes dynamically that I handled it.

My requirement is have to push these object in the starttime Array using `setState` in reactjs.

expected result as below.

```
this.state = {
   frequency: {
      starttime: [{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"},
         {time:"01:30",timezone:"UST"},
         {time:"13:00",timezone:"UST"},...],
      },
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is something that’s usually covered in react tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have the data in a variable called `newTimes` that need to be updated as `starttime` in the state. Then below is one of the ways you can update it. You can refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for more details about how previous state can be used while updating.

```
let newTimes = [{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"}, {time:"01:30",timezone:"UST"}];
this.setState(state => ({
  ...state,
  frequency: {
    starttime: [...state.frequency.starttime, ...newTimes]
  }
}))
```

If you want to remove certain elements from the `newTimes` array based on on a condition, then [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will be handy. For simplicity I'm considering to filter out the data based on `timezone`, below is the example

```
let newTimes = [{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"}, {time:"01:30",timezone:"UST"}, {time:"16:45",timezone:"GMT"}];
//Removing all the timezones which are of "UST".
//You can change this condition as per your requirement.
const filteredTimes = newTimes.filter(({ timezone }) => timezone !== "UST");
this.setState(state => ({
  ...state,
  frequency: {
    starttime: [...state.frequency.starttime, ...filteredTimes]
  }
}))
```

There are different ways of removing duplicates from an array, please refer below

- Using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
let newTimes = [{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"}, {time:"01:30",timezone:"UST"}, {time:"16:45",timezone:"GMT"}, {time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"},{time:"20:15",timezone:"PST"},{time:"12:30",timezone:"IST"}];

const removeDuplicates = (times) => {
  const finalRes = times.reduce((res, timeObj) => {
    const { time, timezone } = timeObj;
    const key = `${time}_${timezone}`;
    //Check if either the time or timezone are not same with any property from the result object. 
    //If either of them is not matching, then add it to the res object
    if(res[key]?.time !== timeObj.time || res[key]?.timezone !== timeObj.timezone) {
      res[key] = {...timeObj}
    }
    return res;
  }, {});

  //Finally return the values of the object by converting it to an array.
  return Object.values(finalRes);
}

console.log(removeDuplicates(newTimes))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

- Using `Array.filter`

```js
let newTimes = [{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"}, {time:"01:30",timezone:"UST"}, {time:"16:45",timezone:"GMT"}, {time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"},{time:"20:15",timezone:"PST"},{time:"12:30",timezone:"IST"}];

const removeDuplicates = (times) => {
  let obj = {};
  return times.filter(timeObj => {
      const {time, timezone} = timeObj;
      const key = `${time}_${timezone}`;
      //Check if the formatted key is already present in the `obj`, if so return false else add the key and then return true.
      return obj[key] ? false: (obj[key] = true, true)
  });
}

console.log(removeDuplicates(newTimes))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: and How to remove the certain Objects in the which was added i starttime?

Comment: I have updated the answer by removing some objects from the data. Please have a look.

Comment: how should not add the duplicate object in the array for example  [{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"},{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"}] i should avoid the duplicate.. is this possible..?

Comment: Yes @Sanjaikumar it is possible. I have updated my answer by adding corresponding snippets, please have a look.

Comment: thanks .. but i asked for avoid adding duplicate object in the array

Comment: Yes, I have taken an example array which has duplicates and added the snippets for removing the duplicates from that array(assuming when `time` and `timezone` are matching they are only considered as duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

Just combine last object  state with new aray of times using spread operator

see example below :

```
let times = [];
times.push({time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"},{time:"01:30",timezone:"UST"});



this.setState({
   ...this.state, // spread here to prevent removing other key object if present
   frequency: {
     starttime : [...this.state.frequency.starttime, ...times] // merge previous value with new array
   }
})
```

Comment: and How to remove the certain Objects in the which was added i starttime?

Comment: how should not add the duplicate object in the array for example  [{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"},{time:"20:15",timezone:"IST"}] i should avoid the duplicate.. is this possible..?